# Insert into a table with a foreign key in mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm being unable to insert into a table with a foreign key

```
String querystate = " insert into state (country_idcountry, State, short, Km2, Capital, Largest City)"
                    + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(querystate);
preparedStmt.setInt(1, cID);
preparedStmt.setString(2, sName);
preparedStmt.setString(3,sShort);
preparedStmt.setInt(4, sArea);
preparedStmt.setString(5, sCapital);
preparedStmt.setString(6, sLargest_city);
preparedStmt.execute();
```

cID its the foreign key, I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong, but i don't know what is it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot connect the database!
at DB_Connect.TryConn(DB_Connect.java:67)
at Main.main(Main.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mas grande) values (1, 'Córdoba', 'CBA', 165421, 'Córdoba', 'Córdoba')' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1192)
at DB_Connect.TryConn(DB_Connect.java:46)
... 6 more
```

Comment: so, some error being thrown or something?

Comment: it says that i have an error in my mysql syntax, but as i did the same with a table that has no foreign key and everything worked.

Comment: please tell us what is the error

Comment: Could you please post the code for database connection. How you are connecting to database??

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Comment: maybe this `, Largest City)"`  will need to quote it if spaces

Comment: It was exactly that, thanks @ScaryWombat

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column with a space in it then the column will need to be quoted

e.g.

```
insert into state (country_idcountry, State, short, Km2, Capital, 'Largest City')"
                + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: In case your column name contains space, single quote may not work for some databases. You can try with backtick like \`Largest City\` . 

But its not recommended to put spaces in table names or table column names.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax is incorrect.

In your prepared statement you should mention only column names in bracket and question mark for each corresponding column. And then you can set value for each column using prepared Statement set methods.

Suppose your table is like below,

> state (country_id int, country text, state text, distance int, capital text, largest_city text)

Then your insert query syntax should be like

```
String query= " insert into state (country_id , country , state , distance , capital , largest_city) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStmt.setInt(1, cID);
preparedStmt.setString(2, cName);
preparedStmt.setString(3,sName);
preparedStmt.setInt(4, distance);
preparedStmt.setString(5, sCapital);
preparedStmt.setString(6, sLargest_city);
preparedStmt.execute();
```

Comment: The problem was not that, the only reason why it didn't work was this:
My code: 
`String querystate = " insert into state (country_idcountry, State, short, Km2, Capital, Largest City)"
                    + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"`
When it should've been
`String querystate = " insert into state (country_idcountry, State, short, Km2, Capital, 'Largest City')"
                    + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"`